# I'm looking for a rechargeable mini keyboard with specific features. Does this instrument exist?

Tags: piano, keyboard

I don't know if what I would like to have, does exists. I'm not a musician.
I would like a mini keyboard with:

- piano and/or rhodes samples
- dynamic keyboard
- integrated speakers
- that you can charge and use with its battery for few hours as if it
  was an iPad
- 2/3 octaves
- smallest as possible, mini keys are good
- minimal design

NB. I'm not looking for a MIDI keyboard or a controller, it needs to have samples and speakers, so that I can play it as standalone instrument.

Does a product like this exist?

thanks

Comment: This question will probably be closed, because we don't really do shopping advice here, but that being said: Yamaha Reface CP.

Comment: @YourUncleBob Yeah, I understand. More than a shopping advice I was looking some help to identify a category of keyboards with those features to simplify the search.

Comment: If you move away from brands like Casio, and look at brands known for professional musical instruments (like Yamaha) you're more likely to find something that's actually useful. Btw, the Reface CP also has an acoustic piano sound as a "hidden feature".

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing as you and the reface cp was the one i choose. Its mainly focus is on rhodes/wurlitzer/cp, but it has also a secret  "real" piano sound (Doesn't sound really good, but the rhodes and wurli is very nice).

I am/was really happy with it, but i dont use it very often nowdays because a big piano makes way more fun to play. But you should definitely check it out.

Comment: How useful are the built-in speakers?

Comment: I think the sound quality is okay. They are not loud enough to compete with an acoustic guitar or so but the max volume is okay for me. If you want to jam with other people you will need an amp or external speakers. I have heard of some people complaining about the left speaker making noises, but i could not find this issue on my speakers.

Answer (score 0):

[Plenty](https://www.casio.com/products/electronic-musical-instruments/mini-keyboards/sa-77) - all of them are marketed as toys, but I see no reason why they wouldn't work for you, unless you have some implicit constraints (like: "must not look like a toy" or "must have dynamic keyboard"). You will need to use rechargeable AA batteries.

Comment: Not heard one yet with a half decent piano or Rhodes sound...

Comment: That's one of the "implicit constraints" :)

Comment: The problem with both would be mostly the lack of velocity sensitive keyboard - even patch from a good sample library would be killed by all the sounds having exactly the same velocity. But I don't know the intentions of the OP - perhaps the instrument is meant as, say, a help for a vocal quartet practice, or something.

Comment: @Tim Have you played the Yamaha Reface CP?

Comment: @YourUncleBob - no, but just listened to it. Well impressed. Thanks. Wonder what the action is like.

Comment: @fdreger indeed the dynamic keyboard was a implicit constraint in my mind :) I made it explicit, otherwise it sounds indeed like a toy. What do you suggest? (beside Reface CP)

Comment: @Tim The best way to judge it, besides trying it out for yourself, is probably Nahre Sol's YouTube channel. She's a classically trained pianist and composer who uses the Reface CP in some of her videos, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtuu2WGY3ng

Comment: @Tim it has a very light action but to get full volume you have to press the keys pretty hard. The dynamics have really been optimized for the little keys.